# Sorting Predis keys PHP

Tags: php, redis

is there any way to order keys that are returns from redis keys command?

```
$keys = $redis->keys('*');
```

I want to return them with the longest expiry time left as element 0 in the array but the above command just brings them back in any order.

Example keys:

chat:ch1:1446759330
chat:ch1:1446760371
chat:ch1:1446760375

Comment: What is `print_r($keys);`?

Comment: It's the correct keys but not in the correct order. the bit after ch1: is time().
I was hoping to arsort($keys); to get them in the order I want but doesn't always work. couldn't find a sort function in predis :(

Comment: You're assuming we know what the output is from this function. Is it an array, text, what?

Comment: It returns an array of strings.

Comment: `sort()` sorts arrays!

Comment: $keys is an associative array so you need to use ksort()